# How to create same root element with namesapce in Xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to copy some part from source XML, since `<xsl:copy>` ignore the root element, I have to create manually (Or there might a better way, please give any advice)

source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:header="http://www.test.com/header" >
    <file_header >
        <header:Header>
            <aaa>123</aaa>
        </header:Header>
    </file_header>
    <someNode>
        <bbb>234</bbb>
    </someNode>
    <target>
        <ccc>ccc</ccc>
        <ddd>ddd</ddd>
    </target>
    <target>
        <ccc>eee</ccc>
        <ddd>fff</ddd>
    </target>
</root>
```

Expected Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:header="http://www.test.com/header" >
    <file_header >
        <header:Header>
            <aaa>123</aaa>
        </header:Header>
    </file_header>
    <someNode>
        <bbb>234</bbb>
    </someNode>
</root>
```

The Xslt I am using is like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:header="http://www.test.com/header">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="{node-name(node())}" namespace="{namespace-uri(node())}">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//target[1]/preceding-sibling::node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the result is not right, the namespace is appear on every child node, but not on root one...
It might seem stupid to you, but please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried replace your `<xsl:template match="/">...` template with following

```
<xsl:template match="/node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="target[1]/preceding-sibling::node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And it seems to be working as you expect.

Comment: Thanks! And would you mind explaining a little..? why /node() could copy the old root? Shouldn't /node() means select all the child nodes of the root?

Comment: IMO the main point is meaning of `/`. It is document node - something like abstract parent of root element - not the root element. In well formed xml document there should be only one root element (hence only one child of document node) so `/node()` should match the root element.